# The application google services framework (process com.google.process.gapps) has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: 2.2-froyo, google-account, force-close

I am using  [nikai tablet NMD8000b](http://www.nikai.com/nikai_electronics_multimedia_internet_device.asp?p=3..) which is on Android 2.2 . Currently device showing **The application google services framework (process com.google.process.gapps) has stopped unexpectedly**
I didn't get any support from the nikai site. How can i rectify and overcome the problem

Comment: See also: [Getting GApps error message](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43569) and [com.google.process.gapps crashing](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20327)

Comment: See also: [How do I stop com.google.process.gaps force closing randomly?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13530)